# Plot of a binary file in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, binary

I have a binary file from which I have to read data. The file consists of a 128x128x243 matrix (hex-formatted) which I have read with the following code:

```
with open("zubal_voxel_man.dat", "rb") as fileHandle:

    dim_x = 128
    dim_y = 128
    dim_z = 243

    data = np.zeros((dim_x,dim_y,dim_z), dtype=np.int)

    for p in range(0, dim_x):
        for q in range (0, dim_y):
            for r in range(0, dim_z):
                data[p][q][r] = ord(fileHandle.read(1))
```

How do I visualize these data with Python? Each x,y,z position has a value from 0 to 255 (grey scale) which I would like to render.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As currently stated, this problem has too many steps to be answered clearly.  I suggest that you break the problem into pieces: 1) read in the data and print a few points to make sure you're doing that right; 2) get the Python data structure to match your data; etc; and if you have any trouble with these steps, ask again for an individual step.

Answer (score 2):

Part of your problem is with the code:

```
datax = data[:,0]
datay = data[:,1]
dataz = data[:,2]
```

Which is not doing what you are expecting of slicing in a single axis it is taking a slice of the Y=0 then of Y=1, Y=2 and plotting them against each other - your other issue is that you have a 3 dimensional array of values which gives each value 4 dimensions X, Y, Z, Value - and you are trying to plot these into a surface. which only has 3 dimensions.

I think that your first priority is to clarify your what your data represents and how it is structured.